# How to override intrinsictContentSize for a view with flexible height and fixed width?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am trying to display custom views in a tableView and letting iOS compute the height of each row using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Unfortunatelly my cell are not properly sized (bad height).

My custom view is defined as followed (I am not using AutoLayout for this part, for many reasons, and I do not want to use it):

```
class MyView : UIView {
    var label: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        addSubview(label)
    }

    func setText(text: String) {
        label.text = text
        setNeedsLayout()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        label.frame = bounds
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        guard let text = label.text else { return .zero }
        let width = bounds.width
        let height = text.heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: width, font: label.font)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Now, I wrapped this custom view in a `UITableViewCell` to use it in a `UITableView`. Here I am using AutoLayout:

```
class MyCell : UITableViewCell {
    var myView: MyView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupCell()
    }

    func setupCell() {
        myView = MyView()
        contentView.addSubview(myView)
        myView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(contentView)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, using the following viewController, I display a cell with a big text to see if its height gets automatically computed:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableView = UITableView()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(view)
        }
        tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 30
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell") as! MyCell
        cell.myView.setText(text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur")
        return cell
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, the cell's height is equal to 21. And this, even though the height returned by the last `intrinsicContentSize` call of `MyView` is 143. Here is a screenshot of the result:
[image]

The cell is sized correctly if it is recycled (I scroll the cell outside the screen):
[image]

I know that the `intrinsictContentSize` of `MyView` uses its frame and it should not, but I have no idea on how to design a UIView subclass that has a flexible height given a fixed width. I thought it would work given the fact I call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` in MyView's `layoutSubviews()`.

How can I change this code to have the good cell's height from start?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why you chose not to use Autolayout here? This is exactly the kind of thing it's great at.

Comment: Because in my real use case, I have something else instead of simply a UILabel. I have a very rich UIView composed of lot of subviews. If I kept autolayout for all of this, I'd end up having performance issue in tableViews.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The documentation suggests that overriding `intrinsicContentSize` may not be the best way to achieve what you want to achieve.  As you've observed, from the [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize) class reference:

> Setting this property allows a custom view to communicate to the layout system what size it would like to be based on its content. This intrinsic size *must be independent of the content frame*, because there’s no way to dynamically communicate a changed width to the layout system based on a changed height, for example.

MyView's `bounds` are not set until after its `intrinsicContentSize` has been requested, and in an auto layout context are not guaranteed to have been set at any time before `layoutSubviews()` is called. There is a way to work around that and pass a width to your custom view for use in `intrinsicContentSize`, however, which I've included as the second option in this answer.

**Option 1: Manual layout by overriding `sizeThatFits(_:)`**

First, in the absence of auto layout, configure MyView and its label subview to size and resize themselves appropriately:

```
//  MyView.swift

func setupView() {
    label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth] // New
    addSubview(label)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    label.sizeToFit() // New
}

override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return label.sizeThatFits(size) // New
}
```

MyView will now size itself according to the size of its label subview, and the label will be sized according to the width of its superview (because of its `.flexibleWidth` autoresizing mask) and its text content (because `numberOfLines` is set to 0).  If MyView had other subviews, you would need to compute and return the total size in `sizeThatFits(_:)`.

Secondly, we want UITableView to be able to compute the height of its cells and your custom subviews according to the manual layout above.  When self-sizing cells, UITableView calls [`systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622623-systemlayoutsizefitting) on each cell, which in turn calls [`sizeThatFits(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622625-sizethatfits) on the cell.  (See [WWDC 2014 Session 226](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/226/).)

The target size or fitting size passed to those methods is the width of the table view with a zero height.  The horizontal fitting priority is `UILayoutPriorityRequired`.  You take control of the self-sizing cell process by overriding one of those methods in your custom cell subclass (the former for auto layout, the latter for manual layout) and using the width of the size passed in to compute and return the height of the cell.

In this case, the size of the cell is the size of `myView`:

```
//  MyCell.swift

override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
    return myView.sizeThatFits(targetSize)
}
```

And you're done.

**Option 2: Auto layout by overriding `intrinsicContentSize`**

As the size of MyView depends on the size of its label, the first step is to ensure that the label is positioned and sized correctly. You've already done this:

```
//  MyView.swift

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    label.frame = bounds
}
```

The second step is to define MyView's intrinsic content size.  In this case, there is no intrinsic width (because that dimension will be determined entirely by the cell or other superview), and the intrinsic height is the intrinsic height of the label:

```
//  MyView.swift

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: label.intrinsicContentSize.height)
}
```

Because your label is a multiline label, its intrinsic height cannot be determined in the absence of a maximum width.  By default, in the absence of a maximum width, UILabel will return an intrinsic content size appropriate for a single line label, which is not what we want.

The only documented way to provide a maximum width to a multiline label for the purpose of computing its intrinsic content size is the [`preferredMaxLayoutWidth`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620534-preferredmaxlayoutwidth) property. The header file for UILabel provides the following comment for that property:

> // If nonzero, this is used when determining -intrinsicContentSize for multiline labels

So the third step is to ensure `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is set to an appropriate width. As the `intrinsicContentSize` property forms part of, and is relevant only to, the auto layout process, and your custom cell subclass is the only part of your code performing auto layout, the appropriate place to set layout preferences is in that class:

```
//  MyCell.swift

override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
    myView.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = targetSize.width
    myView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()

    return super.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: horizontalFittingPriority, verticalFittingPriority: verticalFittingPriority)
}
```

If MyView had more than one multiline label, or if you preferred to keep the subview hierarchy of MyView hidden from its superview, you could equally create your own `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property on MyView and follow through.

The above code will ensure MyView computes and return an appropriate `intrinsicContentSize` based on the content of its multiline label, and that the size is invalidated on rotation.

Comment: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric saved my entiere day thank you

Comment: second option does not work if view is in UIStackView because systemLayoutSizeFitting is not called

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple different things going on here that gives you this behavior.

You'll notice that if you print the height value inside of intrinsicContentSize, it gets called first with a width of zero, as the view has no size yet. Then you're forcing label's frame in layoutSubviews. At this point, the cell is **already laid out** and will not be immediately redrawn even though you're using invalidateIntrinsicContentSize! When you scroll the cell out of view and back in, it is redrawn at that point.

The brute-force solution is to calculate the correct height of the label inside of layoutSubviews. Alternatively, calculate, save and store it when setting the text string to be applied later. I'd still favor trying the constraint-based solution first, it's been performant for me, even with multiple variable-height labels. A bit of a hack would be to base the width off the *superview* - which will already have a width:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    guard
        let text = label.text,
        let parent = superview
    else { return .zero }
    let width = parent.bounds.width
    let height = text.heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: width, font: label.font)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

Additionally, you're using flexible heights and constraining all of the edges of MyView to the Content View. Typically you'd constrain top/leading/trailing from MyView to the Content View, and then the bottom of Content View to MyView. That way the content view's height will always flex to the height of MyView.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I cannot use the superview hack: in this use case it would probably work because I want `MyView`'s width to be equal to the cell's width, but somewhere else in my app I don't want that.

Comment: Then you'll have to use one of the other approaches I suggested. The root problem is that on first run, you have no cell width! You need additional information to get the size correct on the first path, or force the cell(s) to redraw.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to invalidate intrinsic size in setter of text instead of doing it in layoutSubview()

```
func setText(text: String) {
    label.text = text
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() // invalidate before layout
    setNeedsLayout()
}
```

also in invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() method you can simply do this

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: label.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)))
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding this to the bottom of `viewDidAppear:`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

There's a bug on table view that sometimes prevents its cell from being laid out correctly the first time it loads.